# nodeJS alternative to IP-Adress or localhost? Avahi-daemon

Tags: node.js

I am using Nodejs with the express, bcrypt and body-parser packages on an ubuntu linux system.
Everything works fine so far.

However, I´ve been wondering if there is an easier way to connect to my website.
Until now, I have to type in my IP adress, e.g. https://XXX.XXX.XXX:3000 to actually see the content.

I´ve already tried avahi-daemon but did not get it work. Whenver I try 'hostname.local' I get the same error: Firefox is unable to connect to server.

However, using the IP-Adress: https://XXX.XXX.XXX:3000 works.

I would like to access my NodeJS sever with something similar to: computername.local

FYI: I just want to use it in my local network at home.

Does anybody have any idea how to get this work?

Comment: This is not node.js specific. You need to learn about TCP/IP and hostname resolution. It's different for different OS but almost all OS supports a hosts file. For unixen like Linux or Mac it's /etc/hosts. I forgot where it is for Windows. If you want other people to also be able to access it with a name you need to learn about DNS and about buying domain names. Note: if you don't mind spending money you can directly use your own domain name even for local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple choices. The easiest,if available, is probably to setup your home router to always assign it the same IP address (how to do that will vary based on your router).  If your router has it available, you could also set a host name for it there in DNS settings.

If your router doesn't have DNS settings available, then you can add a line to each of your home computers /etc/hosts file (if memory serves Windows has it in C:\etc\hosts).  Let's say the IP you give the server is 172.16.1.11, your hosts entry would be

172.16.1.11  computername.local

You could also setup your own DNS server in your house, possibly even on the same machine as has your node app, and then configure it to handle the one address before forwarding DNS requests for others to your ISP but that seems like overkill if you have just one app.